# Showing posted data on another website in real time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How i show data postet in another website to mysql database, in real time on main page of website using PHP and that any new data is displayed in a new line.

Datas that i need show are: name, and finish time (from race).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) JS method on main page of website and do [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) requests to your server to update data.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!